Why am I getting two different answers using different methods?
I was doing this question:
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\log(1+2h)+2\log(1+h)}{h^2}$
Now using L'Hopital's Rule I was easily able to arrive at the answer which is 1. But when I used the formula for limits of log I arrived at a different answer which was 0. My methodology was:
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\log(1+2h)+2\log(1+h)}{h^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\log(1+2h)}{h^2} + \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\log(1+h)}{h^2}$
$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\log(1+2h)}{2h*\frac{h}{2}}+\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\log(1+h)}{h*h}$
Now, using $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1$, we have
$\frac{-2}{h}+\frac{2}{h} = 0$
Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Shouldn’t it be h that goes to zero in the limits?

If we have two functions $f$ and $g$ and a point $c$, in order to say $$\lim_{x\to c} [f(x)+g(x)]=\lim_{x\to c} f(x)+\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$$
we must first ensure that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x) $ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$ exist and are finite.
In this case, using, as you mentioned, $\log(1+t)\sim t$, we get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\log(1+2x)}{x^2} =\lim_{x\to 0}-\dfrac{2}{x}$$
and $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\log(1+x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2}{x}$$
As the limits do not exist, we cannot split the limit of the sum into the sum of the limits. The correct value can be obtained, as you already said, using L'Hôpital's rule and it is equal to $1$.

Since both $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\log(1+2h)}{h^2}$  and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\log(1+h)}{h^2}$ tend to infinity, you can't separate the limit because the numerators go to $0$ with different speeds.
An example: $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
With your method:$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}-\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}=0$$

Umm...isn't $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$..so the answer should be $1$ right?

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous Right, I was going to write cosine of x. Thank you.
